# Using GORM, record is saved into the database, but when i try to retrieve the same entity it gives the saved id+1

Tags: grails, grails-orm

```
def saveTldAndUpdateTimestamp(EntityTld entityTld) {
        log.debug("EntityTldService saveTldAndUpdateTimestamp Start")
        entityTld.lastUpdated = new Date()

        if (!entityTld.dateCreated) {
            entityTld.dateCreated = entityTld.lastUpdated
        }
        EntityTld savedEntityTld = entityTld.save(flush: true, failOnErrors: true)
        log.debug("EntityTldService saveTldAndUpdateTimestamp Exit Entity ID:: ${savedEntityTld?.id}")
        return savedEntityTld
    }
```

Example : savedEntityTld with id - 200 in the database.
However in the log statement, instead of printing 200, it prints 201 and the rest of the values is similar to the record of id = 200.
FYI, the table corresponding to the domain EntityTld has a GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY column for the id.
The main objective here is, after saving the entitytld record into the database table, i need the saved id and will insert a new record into table2 (this id being one of the columns in table2)

Comment: The most likely problem is you reusing the saved entity in some way or doing something off-by-one in e.g. an outer loop, when saving. It's a reassuring assumption, that databases are not out there to confuse you by adding numbers to your IDs.

Comment: The log statement right after the save, prints 201 and not 200. I am not reusing the saved entity.

Comment: Have you logged the incoming ID? What database is this? Do you use some sort of combined primary key?

Comment: This is DB2, no its not a combined primary key.

Comment: Figured out the issue, my bad. There was another job on another server pointing to the same DB and hence the inconsistency with the ids.